# Active Admin Checboxes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activeadmin

I'm working with active admin and ruby on rails.

I have a Boolean column named verified. I want that column value to be displayed as a check box. For a true value a checked check box and non checked for false values. This check box should be able to take inputs

Comment: What's the problem??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to be more understandable and use google first. Welcome to http://api.rubyonrails.org/ - there are all needs classes and helpers and etc.

```
check_box_tag 'accept'
# => <input id="accept" name="accept" type="checkbox" value="1" />

check_box_tag 'rock', 'rock music'
# => <input id="rock" name="rock" type="checkbox" value="rock music" />

check_box_tag 'receive_email', 'yes', true
# => <input checked="checked" id="receive_email" name="receive_email" type="checkbox" value="yes" />

check_box_tag 'tos', 'yes', false, class: 'accept_tos'
# => <input class="accept_tos" id="tos" name="tos" type="checkbox" value="yes" />

check_box_tag 'eula', 'accepted', false, disabled: true
# => <input disabled="disabled" id="eula" name="eula" type="checkbox" value="accepted" />
```